# Aggregation based on years

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have a table X from which I am selecting below four columns as a subset for my calculation. Below is the sample data set for just one employee.

```
Date_key    Emp_num Salary  Bonus                                       
201001      54343    543    50                                      
201002      54343    453    50                                      
201101      54343    453    100                                     
201106      54343    765    50                                      
201208      54343    777    100
```

If I want to find out the avg of employee salary and bonus.. I can write a query which gives me avg for an employee over whole period of time..

`select date_key,emp_num,avg(salary),avg(bonus) group by date_key,emp_num`..

But I want to find the avg of the salary for 1 year,2 years,3 years…10 years..  However, I wasn't able to achieve the desired result by myself. The result dataset should look like;

```
Emp_num Avg(salary)-2008    Avg(Bonus)-2008 Avg(salary)-2008&2009   Avg(Bonus)-2008&2009    Avg(salary)-2008 to 2010    Avg(Bonus)-2008 to 2010 Avg(salary)-2008 to 2011    Avg(Bonus)-2008 to 2011 Avg(salary)-2008 to 2012    Avg(Bonus)-2008 to 2012
54343   0   0   0   0   498 50  553.5   62.5    598.2   70
```

Comment: This is quitte complicated. I would cut it up in 2 steps. First get the sum per year, then the average for each period.

Comment: I think pivot can help, but i see you want create dynamic colums from date_key column, but it's not possible in oracle, as far i have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have  a solution which gives the result in columns, perhaps you can PIVOT it.

```
with t as
  (select Emp_num, substr(date_key,1,4) as year, 
    avg(salary) over (partition by Emp_num order by Date_key rows unbounded preceding) as avg_sal,
    avg(bonus) over (partition by Emp_num order by Date_key rows unbounded preceding) as avg_bon,
    row_number() over (partition by Emp_num, substr(date_key,1,4) order by Date_key desc) as R
  from Table1)
select EMP_NUM, YEAR, AVG_SAL, AVG_BON
from t
where R = 1;


EMP_NUM     YEAR    AVG_SAL     AVG_BON
-------------------------------------------
54343       2010    498         50
54343       2011    553.5       62.5
54343       2012    598.2       70
```

See example [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84b2d/14)

Comment: that's a great solution +1, but, pivot this query, without hardcoding years?

Answer (score 1):

To make these columns, you would have to know the years beforehand:

```
select 
  emp_num,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) = '2008' then salary end) as avg_salary_2008,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) = '2008' then bonus end) as avg_bonus_2008,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2009' then salary end) as avg_salary_2008to2009,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2009' then bonus end) as avg_bonus_2008to2009,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2010' then salary end) as avg_salary_2008to2010,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2010' then bonus end) as avg_bonus_2008to2010,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2011' then salary end) as avg_salary_2008to2011,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2011' then bonus end) as avg_bonus_2008to2011,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2012' then salary end) as avg_salary_2008to2012,
  avg(case when substr(Date_key,1,4) between '2008' and '2012' then bonus end) as avg_bonus_2008to2012
from employees
group by emp_num;
```

(If you don't know the years beforehand, you can still select the years first and then build your query dynamically.)